# Titanium Android Geolocation Permission for OS older than 6.0

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

So I have successfully gotten Geolocation permission working for Android 6.0 and later but I can't get it to work for Android 4.4.4.

I keep getting these errors in the console

```
 dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
[DEBUG] :  dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
```

This is coming from this

```
var hasLocationPermissions = Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);
```

Now I added the following permissions in the TiApp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Camera Permissions -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Still no luck. Here is the code I use to do this. I even tried to circumvent the by checking the version

```
Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_HIGH;
    Titanium.Geolocation.purpose = 'Get Current Location to search local Items';
    var hasLocationPermissions = Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS);

    if (Titanium.Platform.model != "Simulator"){
        Ti.API.info("ANDROID VERSION:"+Ti.Platform.version);
        if(Alloy.Globals.versionCompare(Ti.Platform.version, "6.0") == -1){
            getCurrentPosition();
        } else
        {
            if(hasLocationPermissions == true){
                 getCurrentPosition();
            } else {
                var win = Alloy.createController('locationPermission', {callback: function(e){
                    Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS, function(e) {
                        if (e.success) {
                            getCurrentPosition();
                        } else {
                            Alloy.Globals.createAlertDialog('There seem to be issues with determining your location.\Please enable Location Services in your Settings to use Fluid');
                        }
                    });
                }}).getView();
                win.open(); 
            }
        }

    } else {
        Ti.API.info("LOCATION FOR SIMULATOR SET TO GALVANIZE - 1644 PLATTE DENVER");
        Alloy.Globals.currentLocation =  {attributes:{coordinates:{"lat": 39.757885, "lng": -105.0082375}}};//Galvanize
        if(successCallback) successCallback();
    }
```

Has anyone solved this? I am on 5.2.0 GA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience android versions prior to 6, or SDK versions below 23, continue to ask for all permissions at install. So this new request for permission when a feature is used is only needed for android 6 and above, or SDK 23 and above. My 5.3GA apps ask for permissions on marshmallow when say the location is requested, but phones with versions <6 ask for permissions at install as usual. My code doesn't have any conditional logic based on android version.

Comment: Mmm. So if I am running it on Genymotion emulator would that permission not show up?

Comment: On my HTC One and S6 it asks for all permissions at install, on my S6 it asks for permissions when they are requested. For the One and S5 they never ask again. For the S6 if I deny it asks the next time location is requested. If I accept it doesn't ask again, unless I reset in settings. I haven't set gps up in genymotion, I test that on the  devices as I am fortunate enough to have a few.

Comment: I should say the S6 is the only one with marshmallow

Comment: Hmm I am looking at your code.  Is Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS for iOS? I will see if I can get access to m code this evening, if not I will look first thing in the morning when I get to work.

Comment: So in the end it was just Genymotion not working no issues on the device. Thanks everyone for your feedback.